# Spring MVC Breadcrumbs

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, breadcrumbs

I'm using Spring MVC + tiles.

Now I want to build the breadcrumbs. So, I'm using this:
https://github.com/pawanspace/BreadCrumb-Spring-MVC

It works well but I get an error in the BreadCrumbInterceptor.

This is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean
            class="dummiesmind.breadcrumb.springmvc.interceptor.BreadCrumbInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And the error:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
```

Just in this line on method BreadCrumbInterceptor.getDeclaredAnnotationsForHandler:

```
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod)handler;
```

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The cast fails because handler isn't an instance of HandlerMethod.
You could check before trying to cast :

```
if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
    // ... code goes here
}
```

However, I don't think that is going to fix your problem.
I recommend parsing url context to create a breadcrumb.